# Python: Complicated iterables

Tags: python, generator, breadth-first-search, iterable

I have seen this piece of code that iterates through certain members of a class if they exists. Notably, in a binary tree, iterating through the child until there are no more children.

Binary tree is defined as..

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

and they have iterated it like this:

```
# type root : TreeNode
def iterateTree(self, root):
    level_list = [root]

    while level_list:

        for item in level_list:
             print(item.val)

        # This iterable seems really complicated for me to understand how they came up with this
        level_list = [child for node in level_list for child in (node.left, node.right) if child]
```

I'm not sure how they came up with that line to iterate through the left and right node, I wouldn't have ever come up with that on the spot... How would I dissect this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read as follows:

```
for node in level_list:
    for child in (node.left, node.right):
        if child:
            child
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, this statement is a pythonic and short-hand way of creating a list.

```
 # This iterable seems really complicated for me to understand how they came up with this
   level_list = [child for node in level_list for child in (node.left, node.right) if child]
```

this is basically a shorthand way of doing the following set of lines:

```
for node in level_list:
    for child in (node.left, node.right):
        if child:
            level_list.append(child)
```

the trick to understanding this shorthand statement is by looking at the peripheral bounding symbols, in this case these are `[` and `]`. which identifies with the list sequence in python. since there are iterators (`for` loops) in the list, we are basically creating or adding elements (variable `child`) in the said list.

/ogs

Comment: Is there any runtime difference between the two? Is the concised shorthand way faster (and/or recommended practice) to do or there is really no difference?

Comment: no runtime difference tbh. however this practice is done by many to save on lines-of-code. i also do this specially if i'm code sprinting.

Comment: @Ogs well not really, it's hard to read and debug. So best practice is to avoid such coding patterns

Comment: @Kalanamith yeah. but there's no runtime difference. hehe. aesthetically - i agree with you, it's hard to read and debug...